# Android App MS SQL Server Authentication only works with WIFI

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, networking

Problem: My Application can successfully connect to a Microsoft SQL 2014 server but only when my phone is connected via WIFI. As soon as I turn WIFI off, I am no longer able to connect. Shouldn't it switch to the 4G connection?

Code:

```
private class AuthenticateDB extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Connection> {

    private OnAuthenticationSuccess mCallbacks;
    private String userName;

    private AuthenticateDB(OnAuthenticationSuccess callbacks){
        this.mCallbacks = callbacks;
    }

    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground(String[]... params) {

        Connection connection;
        userName = params[0][0];
        String password = params[0][1];
        String serverIP = params[0][2];

        String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + serverIP + "/" +
                DatabaseContract.DATABASE_NAME + ";instance=" +
                DatabaseContract.DATABASE_INSTANCE + ";";


        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,userName,password);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Connection connection) {
        mCallbacks.notifyAuthenticationComplete(connection,userName);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the connection IP address from using a DNS address to the actual IP address and also tried it with & without a port number (1433). The IP i am using is not localhost or 127.0.0.1, or the server name. It is the actual WAN IP address which again only works with my phone connected to WIFI.

Error:

```
09-25 12:45:45.380    7338-7380/com.periapsislabs.assettracker W/System.err﹕
ava.sql.SQLException: Unable to get information from SQL Server: 98.219.231.54.
```

Comment: When you turn wifi off you can't connect?  Why would you expect anything different?

Comment: Shouldn't it switch the 4G? Or am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here:

1. Your device isn't set up to automatically switch to the 4G connection.
2. Your mobile provider is blocking that type of traffic or the port.
3. Your connection times out due to increased latency of the 4G connection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, As for #1 i tried started the application with wifi completely off so it was purely a 4g connection from the start, with no luck. #2 I have Verizon Wireless, is this a port they block? #3 I changed the timeout on the server to no timeout and still get the same results.